# Trying to append unique XML attributes to nodes using RapidXML

Tags: c++, c++11, rapidxml

I want to append attributes to each node found in a root tag in an iterator, and I want the attribute to be `id` with indices assigned to them. Here is the block of code used for iterating over the child nodes, allocating and appending each attribute to each node:

```
for (xml_node<>* node = root->first_node("lang")->first_node("strings")->first_node();
     node; node = node->next_sibling()) 
{
    node->append_attribute(
        document.allocate_attribute(
            "id", (std::to_string(index)).c_str()
            )
        );
    index += 1;
}
```

After inspection, it seems that `document.allocate_attribute` isn't creating a new pointer as I expected it to, since the most of the `id` attributes in the XML output produced by my function `print_document`, show mostly duplicate values, i.e.:

```
<translations>
    <lang>
        <strings>
        ...
        <s id="895">string1</s>
        <s id="895">string2</s>
        <s id="895">string3</s>
        ...
        </strings>
    </lang>
</translations>
```

`print_document` is simply:

```
void print_document(xml_document<> &document)
{
    rapidxml::print(std::cout, document, 0);
}
```

Given that I'm not overly concerned with memory usage, how can I ensure that each appended attribute value is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic stumble due to RapidXML's string ownership design.

When you add an attribute, RapidXML doesn't make a copy of the attribute string - it just stores the pointer, which then goes out of scope and frequently gets reused for the next attribute...

Use `allocate_string` to help you.

Try this:-

```
document.allocate_attribute("id", allocate_string(std::to_string(index).c_str()))
```